# Вызов деструктора класса при сбое в работе скрипта

Tags: ооп, php

Вызывается ли деструктор при сбое в работе скрипта? Например, если скрипт прерывает работу из-за лимитов сервера, либо если его закрывают через консоль, либо возникат фатальная ошибка? Могут ли быть такие случаи, когда скрипт прекратил работу, а деструктор класса не был вызван?

Comment: Например, все Fatal error

Comment: Насколько помю (а помнить могу неверно) хэндлеры `register_shutdown_function()` все-таки будут вызваны, поэтому важные места можно попробовать обойти таким путем.

Comment: Да, но нужно проверить, что они корректно отработают в тех случаях, когда продолжение выполнения вообще не возможно.

Простой пример: синтаксическая ошибка в файле, подключенном через require

Comment: В общем, если процесс убивают через консоль, либо скрипт останавливается из-за max_execution_time или нехватки памяти, то деструктор точно будет вызван?

Comment: >если процесс убивают через консоль

Если процесс убивается `kill -9`, то какой деструктор?

Comment: @kir55rus, на SO [пишут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23956590), что как раз-таки через консоль не вызывается.

Comment: @Fike, [pcntl][1]?


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-signal.php

Comment: @Johny, против SIGKILL (9) не может быть никакого обработчика, по определению. Это обусловлено архитектурой ОС, а не конкретного языка. Убить процесс - это значит именно "убить насмерть", а не "ранить" или вежливо попросить его завершиться.